# Get all spreadsheet data to client side first, then "find row number and same row values using javascript for a specific value"

Tags: javascript

Code.js

/**
     * Load Spreadsheet by ID
     * Get all Sheets present in that spreadsheet
     * Loop through each sheet 
     * Create an object with sheet's name as Key of the object
     * and sheets data as Value of the object
     * Return the key-value paired object
     */

```
    function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
    .setTitle("Exam Result");
}


function getAllResult()
{   
  var id = '1da6d8rfWgZrG2Cnpyho6YDx0C7Me4o20rM4PhDi8yCY'; // ID of the Result spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // get all the sheets in the spreadsheeet
  var allSheetsData = {}; // initialize javascript object  
  var sheetName = '';
  var sheetValues;
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetName = sheets[i].getName();    
    sheetValues = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues();    
    allSheetsData[sheetName] = sheetValues;    
  }
  //Logger.log(allSheetsData);  
  return allSheetsData;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>    
      window.onload = function() {        
        init(); // initial function to run on page load
      };

      // initializing object that will be storing all result data
      var allResultData = {}; 

      // loading image
      var loading = '<img width="25px" ' + 
                    'src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/PshQKOjKS5j6IEaEXZ6r7-JOFZwYOBopBt82Q-kTGdRcW6wi3SBHDAUHebb2yreOeTpGfzgs=w1280-h661"> ' + 
                    'Loading...';

      /**
       * First function to run on page load
       */
      function init() {
        document.getElementById('progressClass').innerHTML = loading; // show loading image

        /**
         * This calls getAllResult() function of Code.gs
         * The returned value from getAllResult() is passed to populateClass(value) function
         * present in this html file
         */
        google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(populateClass)
              .getAllResult();
      }

      /**
       * Second function to run after init() function
       * Populates the "Class" select box
       */
      function populateClass(value) {
        document.getElementById('progressClass').innerHTML = ''; // hide loading image
        allResultData = value; // all result data is stored in allResultData object
        var className = Object.keys(value);
        var classes = '<option>Please Select</option>';
        for (i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
          classes += "<option>" + className[i] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("class").innerHTML = classes;
      }

      function populateSymbolNumber(value)
      {  
      {var day = "<option>Day</option>";        
        var data = allResultData[value]
        for (i=1; i < 32; i++) { // start from i=1, skipping 1st row as it's heading
          day += "<option value="+i+">" + data[i][3] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day;}

        {var month = "<option>Month</option>";        
        var data = allResultData[value]
        for (i=1; i < 13; i++) { // start from i=1, skipping 1st row as it's heading
          month += "<option value="+i+">" + data[i][4] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;}

        {var year = "<option>Year</option>";        
        var data = allResultData[value]
        for (i=1; i < 122; i++) { // start from i=1, skipping 1st row as it's heading
          year += "<option value="+i+">" + data[i][5] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year;}

        {var symbol = "<option>Please Select</option>";        
        var data = allResultData[value]
        for (i=1; i < data.length; i++) { // start from i=1, skipping 1st row as it's heading
          symbol += "<option value="+i+">" + data[i][0] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = symbol;}
      }

      /**
       * Show name of student and marks result
       */
      function submitForm(value) {        
        var grade = document.getElementById("class");
        var gradeValue = grade.options[grade.selectedIndex].value;

        var classResult = allResultData[gradeValue];

        var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol");
        var day = document.getElementById("day");
        var month = document.getElementById("month");
        var year = document.getElementById("year");
        var symbolText = symbol.options[symbol.selectedIndex].text;
        var DayText = day.options[day.selectedIndex].text;
        var MonthText = month.options[month.selectedIndex].text;
        var YearText = year.options[year.selectedIndex].text;
        var symbolValue = symbol.options[symbol.selectedIndex].value;
        var dob = DayText + '-' + MonthText + '-' + YearText;

        var marks = '';
        var headerRow = classResult[0];
        //console.log(headerRow);
        for (i = 1; i < headerRow.length; i++) { // start from i=1, skipping 1st column as it contains symbol number
          marks += headerRow[i] + ': ' + classResult[symbolValue][i] + '<br>';
        }

        var result = "Symbol Number: " + symbolText + '<br>' + marks;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

        return false;              
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="form">
      <table cellpadding="5px">
        <tr>
          <td>Class</td>
          <td>
            <select id="class" onchange="populateSymbolNumber(this.value)">
              <option value="">Please Select</option>  
            </select>
            <span id="progressClass"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Symbol</td>
          <td>
            <select id="day">
              <option value="">Day</option>
            </select>            
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="month">
              <option value="">Month</option>
            </select>            
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="year">
              <option value="">Year</option>
            </select>            
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="symbol">
              <option value="">Please Select</option>
            </select>            
          </td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <button onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="result" style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

There is a variable

```
var dob = DayText + '-' + MonthText + '-' + YearText;
```

I want to find row number for the "dob" value in the loaded data.
Google sheet has value as 30-December-1992.

Comment: Do you want to show spreadsheet data on HTML? and later get the numbers and grade basis of name? Also, Please share your code.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, and a proper question here on this site should contain of a bit more, than just your requirement.

Comment: There are some modification in question like, I want to run code on client side using Javascript.

Comment: Could I get reply if solution available at any way.